# How to use the BreakPlot function to avoid unnecessary blank space with boxplot?

Tags: matlab, plot, boxplot

I find this amazing tool which Produces a plot who's y-axis skips to avoid unnecessary blank space https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21864-breakplot. I want to use breakPlot function with boxplot. How can I call the BreakPlot function to avoid unnecessary blank space  data from 20 to 50 on the y-axis? Here is the code:

```
A = [59 4.9329; 
59 6.8063; 
59 4.8889; 
61 6.3772; 
57 4.8113; 
60 4.6193; 
59 6.1924; 
59 4.0577; 
60 7.5035; 
58 4.6016; 

58 5.0844]; 


boxplot(A,'Labels',{'$\pi_1$','$\pi_2$'})

%BreakPlot(A,10,40,'Line'); 

bp = gca; 
bp.XAxis.TickLabelInterpreter = 'latex'; 
xlabel('Data set'')

ylabel('Computation time')
```

Comment: This function is simply not compatible with boxplots. You have to write your own "boxplotbreak" function. But why don't you just use a subplot ?

Comment: Could you please guide me with subplot ?

Comment: [subplot documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)

Comment: But it allows to have two plots. not to have one plot with configuring the y axis